# diffeomorphism and product of open sets

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $D$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Is $D\times\mathbb{R}^2$ always diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$ ?
I think this is not true intuitively, but I can't find the counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, that is not true. $\mathbb{R}^4$ is connected, and $D\times\mathbb{R}^2$ is not if you take $D$ to be disconnected. This means these varieties are not homeomorphic. But what if $D$ is connected? Well then there are plenty of other topological properties that could fail.

Answer (score 2):

You can pick your space $D$ to be the open annulus in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\{ (x,y) | r_1^2 < x^2+y^2<r_2^2\}, r_1, r_2 >0$. $D 
\times \mathbb{R}^2$ is not simply connected, so it is not even homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$.

I should also note the following: it is sketchy to judge whether two sets are are diffeomorphic, or even homeomorphic. In order to say that two sets are homeomorphic they must be endowed with a topology, which gives a sense for what points are "close" to what. I've assumed that we're using the natural topology inherited from embedding the space in the plane. But even then, we need something called a differentiable structure to gauge whether two manifolds are diffeomorphic. It is entirely possible to have $D=\mathbb{R}^2$, and still have a different manifold than $\mathbb{R}^4$; this is called exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: I'd like to make an observation on the "$D=\Bbb R^2$" part: while there exist exotic differentiable structures on $\Bbb R^4$, exotic $\Bbb R^2$ do not exist. So, if $\times$ is meant as product of manifolds instead of topological spacese (which is reasonable), then the meaning of $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^2$ is unambiguous (and it's indeed standard $\Bbb R^4$). By the Riemann mapping theorem, it should be the same when $D$ is any simply connected open subset of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @Aurey @G.Sassatelli/ Thank you :)